# escape content of variable for cd

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell, I loop through files and create a folder with each file's name to put some data there.

```
$files = @("[som]video.mkv")
$tmp_location = "." 
# to reproduce just do it on files with a filename like [somen_id]restofname.ext 
foreach ($file in $files){
    $base_input = ([io.fileinfo]$file).basename
    # base input may be a file called: [somen_id]restofname.ext 
    $tmp_dir = "$tmp_location/$base_input"
    mkdir $tmp_dir  # this line works and the directory is created
    # do some stuff first before cd
    cd $tmp_dir #this does not work

}
```

`cd` fails to handle the tmp_dir variable when it has special characters like `[]`, but `mkdir` (and even `rm`) create/delete that directory just fine, which is a very inconsistent behavior in Powershell, I would expect it to either fail for all or work for all!

Any idea how to escape the variable such that it becomes readable to `cd`

(ofc in real life my array is not just 1 filename written by hand, but this example shows the error too)

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't put `[]` in path names.  Powershell and .net will have a lot of trouble with them.

Comment: @js2010, the problem is PowerShell-specific, due to _its_ wildcard language considering `[` and `]` metacharacters. I don't think the underlying .NET APIs are affected.

Comment: @js2010 `"I wouldn't put [] in path names"`, not really a choice... not in my particular use-case at least

Comment: It's a bad choice.

Comment: @js2010 sure, let's make a new world where no one uses an allowed character in file name, and force all people to rename their files before they can use my software because they make bad choices.  It your app does not allow such thing, despite the language having workarounds to support it, then you are the one making bad choices.

Comment: besides, I don't see what value you are adding to the question. It's like  "how do I build a car" , "don't build a car", thanks for the rich answer. I asked how to handle a special case, not how to not handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use the **`-LiteralPath`** parameter to pass a path meant to be interpreted *literally* (verbatim) to the `Set-Location` cmdlet,  which `cd` is a built-in *alias* of; by default (via the positionally implied `-Path` parameter), it is interpreted as a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards):

```bash
# * "cd" is a built-in alias of "Set-Location"
# * "sl" is the preferable, PowerShell-idiomatic built-in alias
# * Interactively, using PowerShell's elastic syntax, 
#   you can shorten "-LiteralPath" to "-l", given that no other parameter name
#   (currently) starts with "l"
# * In PowerShell (Core) 7+, "-lp" is an official alias.
cd -LiteralPath $tmp_dir
```

The same applies analogously to `rm` (unlike what your question implies), which is a built-in alias of `Remove-Item`.

By contrast, `mkdir` (which is a wrapper function for `New-Item -ItemType Directory`) *implicitly* treats its argument *literally*.

Read on for details.

---

As for **what you tried**:

While **`cd` and `mkdir` *look* like their `cmd.exe` counterparts**, they **are *not***:

- `cd` is a built-in alias of the [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) cmdlet.
- `mkdir` is a built-in *wrapper function* for the [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) cmdlet, with implicitly applied argument `-ItemType Directory`.
  (On *Unix*-like platforms, `mkdir` isn't an alias at all and instead refers to the external `/bin/mkdir` utility).

To learn what command a given name (ultimately) refers to in PowerShell, use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet; e.g. `Get-Command cd`)

Thus,

> ```bash
> cd $tmp_dir
> ```

is equivalent to the following call, given that **`Set-Location` binds a *positional* argument** (one not preceded by the target parameter name) **to its `-Path` parameter**:

```bash
Set-Location -Path $tmp_dir
```

***Most* PowerShell cmdlets interpret `-Path` arguments as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)**, including - perhaps surprisingly - `Set-Location`.<sup>[1]</sup>

*Typically*, the distinction between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` doesn't matter, given that `*` and `?` - the usual wildcard characters - aren't even *allowed* in file and directory names (at least on Windows).

However, the problem is that **in *PowerShell's* wildcard language `[` and `]` *also* have special meaning** (they form character sets - e.g. `[abc]` and/or character ranges - e.g. `[a-c]`), which **conflicts with *literal* use of `[` and `]` in file names**, and necessitates the use of `-LiteralPath` for disambiguation.<sup>[2]</sup>

**By contrast**, **[`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)'s (possibly positionally implied) `-Path` parameter *acts like `-LiteralPath`***, because interpreting a path argument as a wildcard expression in the context of *creating* a file or directory is pointless. That's why you had no problem creating a directory whose path literally contains `[` and `]` with `mkdir`.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

##### Why aliases named for a *different* shell's commands - such as `cd` and `mkdir` - are *best avoided* in PowerShell:

In a problematic attempt to ease the migration pain for `cmd.exe` users (and in part also for users of POSIX-compatible shells), PowerShell decided to define built-in aliases and wrapper functions that are named for `cmd.exe`'s internal commands, whereas PowerShell's analogous internal commands, the so-called *cmdlets*, have very different names.

The latter isn't problematic per se - except that by their use you're missing out on the benefits of PowerShell's standard verb-noun naming convention (e.g., `Set-Location`), which also extends to how *aliases* are formed, given that the [approved verbs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) have official alias forms (e.g., `s` for `Set-`; therefore, `sl` is another, but *PowerShell-idiomatic* `Set-Location` alias).

What *is* problematic, however, is that **PowerShell commands have [*very different syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) from `cmd.exe`'s**.

If you use names such as `cd` and `mkdir`, you'll be tempted to think that, e.g. `cd` and `mkdir` function the same way as in `cmd.exe` - which is only true in the most basic of use cases, however.

**It's best to use the true PowerShell command names or - for brevity in *interactive* use - their *PowerShell* aliases**, which are (reasonably) predictably formed, as discussed above (e.g., `sl` for `Set-Location` and `ni` for `New-Item`)

---

<sup>[1] By contrast,  `cmd.exe`'s `cd` command does *not* accept wildcards. With `Set-Location`, wildcard support is of conceptual necessity limited, because the wildcard expression must resolve to *exactly one* matching directory.</sup>

<sup>[2] Alternatively, with `-Path` you can *escape* `[` and `]` as `` `[ `` and `` `] ``, respectively, but this kind of escaping doesn't work consistently as of PowerShell 7.3.0 - see [GitHub issue #7999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7999).</sup>

<sup>[3] This parameter-naming inconsistency is unfortunate; arguably, `-LiteralPath` should at least be supported as a parameter *alias name*  for `-Path`.  That said, as of PowerShell 7.3.0, there is actually a case where `-Path` currently *is* interpreted as a wildcard expression, namely when *combined with the `-Name` parameter*, but this should be considered a *bug* - see [GitHub issue #17106](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17106).</sup>