# Why am I not able to see the hidden files using " ls -a" command in Powershell...?

Tags: powershell

after initializing it with git init commamnd, I am getting the following error. Please help to resolve it.

[image: solve error]

Comment: `-Force` to see hidden and system files

Comment: Welcome! I see you are a new contributor. It is better to include the error message embedded in your question rather than a screenshot. If you edit your answer to include this, be sure to format it as well.

Comment: The -a is an argument on the command line.  Depending on the method methods you are using a argument is not just text, it must be declared as an array of arguments.  So you can try something like this $arguments = @("-a"); ls $arguments

Comment: @jdweng, your suggestion makes no difference with respect to calling _external programs_, and - assuming that `-a` is a _parameter name_ - _breaks_ calls to PowerShell-native commands, such as in this case (given that, on Windows, `ls` is an alias of `Get-ChildItem`). Your comment is an unhelpful distraction.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Don't use `ls -a` in PowerShell (on Windows); use the following instead:

```bash
# 'gci' is the PowerShell-idiomatic alias of the 'Get-ChildItem' cmdlet,
# which is the analog of the 'ls' utility on Unix-like platforms.
# -Force asks that *hidden* file be shown too.
gci -Force
```

---

- On Windows, `ls` is a built-in *alias* of the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet, whose syntax is very different from that of the standard `ls` *utility* available on Unix-like platforms.

  - **PowerShell aliases named for the commands of a different shell / the standard utilities of a different platform are *best avoided***, given their syntactic incompatibility - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591072/45375).
- Use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to determine which command a given name (ultimately) refers to.
- Use [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) or `Get-Command -Syntax` to see a command's [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax).
- `-Force` is the switch parameter that requests that `Get-ChildItem` show *hidden* items too, analogous to `ls -A` on Unix (there's is *no* `ls -a` analogue, which would include listing `.` and `..`, which is rarely useful, however).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `ls -a` translates to `Get-ChildItem -a`.
- PowerShell's parameter names are typically *words* (e.g. `-Attributes`) rather than mere *letters* (e.g., `-a`)
- If a given parameter name is a *prefix* of a full parameter name, PowerShell *infers* the full parameter name, as long as the prefix is *unique*, a feature that PowerShell calls *elastic syntax*, meant for *interactive*  convenience only (in *scripts*, parameter names should always be spelled out in full, both for readability and long-term stability).
- If it *isn't* unique, the error you've encountered occurs, given that PowerShell cannot predictably infer which parameter you meant to target.
- In determining the uniqueness of a parameter-name prefix, parameter *aliases* are considered as well, even though the *error message* only mentions the *original* names of these parameters:

  - Specifically, parameter `-Directory -File -Hidden -ReadOnly -System` are mentioned in the error message, all of which have alias names that *start with `a`*.
  - You can list the relevant parameters and their aliases as follows:

    ```bash
    (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).ParameterSets.Parameters | Where-Object Aliases -Like a* | Select-Object Name, Aliases -Unique
    ```