# Positional parameter cannot be found - env file

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

```bash
SET PORT=3000 ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
```

This is the command I am attempting to run. I have node installed and this is my first time trying to use this environment. My employers think there is some problem because I am on a Windows machine, and they ususally only work with Mac. I am getting the following error:

```
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.env.crkeng'.
```

I have tried this in powershell and cmd. I only get the error in powershell, but either way nothing happens when the commend is run. I have tried enclosing different args in quotes as I've seen some people suggest on other posts, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas on how I could fix this for a Windows environment?

Comment: As an aside re the error message: In PowerShell,  `SET` is - unfortunately - an alias of the [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlet, which not only does _not_ create _environment_ variables  - unlike `SET` in `cmd.exe`, whose syntax you're using - but whose syntax also differs from the latter: `PORT=3000` is interpreted as the variable _name_, `./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd` as the _value_, `-f` as the `-Force` switch, and the presence of _additional_, syntactically unexpected arguments causes the error you saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for an equivalent of the following syntax commonly used in Unix (POSIX-compatible) shells such as Bash, which allows you to **define an "ephemeral" environment variable that exists for a given command (child process) only**:

```bash
# Unix shells such as Bash only:
# Create a command-scoped PORT environment variable with value 3000
# It is *only* defined for the child process created by the call.
PORT=3000 ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
```

- **Neither `cmd.exe` nor PowerShell offer such a syntax**, and these two shells fundamentally have very different syntax.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - This applies as of PowerShell 7.3.x, though there is a **proposal to introduce support for such "ephemeral" environment variables in a future PowerShell version** - see [GitHub issue #3316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316).
- Instead, **you must define the variable *first*, in a *separate statement*** and then call the target program.

  - You may also want to *undefine* the variable / restore its previous value afterwards.

---

**Concrete solutions**:

Note:

- The following uses your command *as specified in your question*. It seems that there may be a problem with that command (*possibly*, `npx env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start` is the correct form), which, however, is *incidental* to the solutions below with respect to specifying the environment variable of interest.

***Without* undefining / restoring afterwards** (env. var. `PORT` will linger, with value `3000`):

- **`cmd.exe`** (note the need to use `\` as the path separator):

  ```bash
  :: Must be *separate statements* on *separate lines*
  :: Enclosure in "..." isn't strictly needed, but a good habit to form.
  set "PORT=3000"
  .\node_modules\.bin\env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
  ```

  - If a program path contains spaces, enclose it in `"..."`
- **PowerShell** (which accepts `\` and `/` interchangeably):

  ```bash
  # *Separate statements*, either on separate lines or separated with ";"
  $env:PORT = 3000; ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
  ```

  - If a program path contains spaces, enclose it in `"..."` ([*expandable* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)) or `'...'` ([*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)) *and invoke it via [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)* (e.g., `& './path with spaces/some.exe' ...`)

***With* undefining / restoring afterwards**:

- **`cmd.exe`**: create a temporary copy of the environment with `setlocal` / `endlocal`

  ```bash
  setlocal
  set "PORT=3000"
  .\node_modules\.bin\env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
  endlocal
  ```
- **PowerShell**: manually save and restore the previous value

  ```bash
  $prevPort = $env:PORT; $env:PORT = 3000
  ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start
  $env:PORT = $prevPort
  ```

  - Note:

    - If env. var. `PORT` didn't previously exist, `$prevPort` contains `$null`, and assigning `$null` to `$env:PORT` later effectively *undefines* (removes) it.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, the creators of PowerShell, in a well-meaning effort to ease the transition from `cmd.exe`, the *legacy* shell, decided to create *aliases* named for the `cmd.exe`'s (internal) commands as well as for some standard executables (including those on Unix-like platforms). This is why `set` - `cmd.exe`'s internal command for setting (what are invariably also *environment*) variables - also exists as a PowerShell alias for its [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlet, even though both the *syntax* and the *purpose* of these commands differ (`Set-Variable` only sets *shell-only* variables) - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591072/45375) for a discussion and PowerShell-idiomatic alternatives.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I've tried in cmd and powershell without undefining, with the methods you gave here. In cmd, when running the second command I get the following error: 


"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."


If I enclose the first arg in quotes, I get an error saying "react-scripts" is not recognized.


When trying in powershell with your method, I also get the "react-scripts" error

Comment: I am still getting the following error on both powershell and cmd: 

"'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
spawn react-scripts ENOENT".

When I try to create default app with "npx create-react-app my-app", there are no probelms. I do not understand why react-scripts is not recognized...

Comment: @BayleySapara, that is an unrelated problem specific to the command line you're invoking. It is `env-cmd` complaining that `react-scripts` is not the name of an executable (neither in the system's path nor in the current dir, given that `cmd.exe` is seemingly used behind the scenes).

Comment: @BayleySapara, in other words: This answer addresses your question _as asked_, namely how to define an environment variable on Windows that a subsequently invoked executable should see. If the call to that executable is flawed, that is a _separate problem_, which - unless there is a simple fix that a quick discussion here can resolve - should be asked _as a new question_.

Comment: @BayleySapara, a _potential_ quick fix would be (note the `npx` addition): `.\node_modules\.bin\env-cmd -f .env.crkeng npx react-scripts start`, or, _perhaps_: `npx env-cmd -f .env.crkeng react-scripts start`

Comment: Thank you for your help, these potential fixes are super helpful and I believe can be used to modify my failes for my Windows machine