# Using Batch to copy file attributes (at least Created,LastWrite,LastAccess) from 1 file to a 2nd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-attributes

I am trying to copy attributes for *.mkv *.mp4 video files. I have found a way to copy file attributes, but it is quite slow as it is calling Powershell to use it commands.

```
powershell ^(ls '!orig-file!'^).CreationTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).CreationTime
powershell ^(ls '!orig-file!'^).LastWriteTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).LastWriteTime
powershell ^(ls '!orig-file!'^).LastAccessTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).LastAccessTime
...................
%%I equals new-file for each FOR loop iteration
```

Is there a way to do this faster without Powershell?

Otherwise, I assume it would be possible to only call Powershell once and copy all 3 or more attributes in 1 line?  I'am assuming that reading each file attribute individually is the only way to copy, but I would prefer all attributes if there are any more to copy.

EDIT:  FULL CODE: (with all remarked/commented lines removed) ( Batch Convert Videos audio from one format to another )

```bash
@ECHO OFF
SETlocal

SET drive="~dp0"
SET string=%CD%  

SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "drive=G:"
SET ^"Exclude-AlltheseFolders=#snapshot,output^"
SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"
SET "Convert_TO=aac"
SET "Codec1=eac3"
SET "Codec2=flac"
SET "Codec3=dts" &SET "Codec4=pcm_s24le" &SET "Codec5=aac" &SET "Codec6=ac3"
SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
SET "KeepOrigAudio=N"
SET "OverWriteFiles=N"
SET "ExtractTime=Y"
SET "time_to_start_from=00:00:10" &SET "duration_to_capture=00:00:15"
SET "TempFilePath=C:\Windows\Temp\ffmpeg-CountingScript-AllFilesInCurrentDirlist%DT%--%HH%.%MM%.%SS%.txt"

IF !ExtractTime! == Y ( SET "FFmpgextractTime= -ss !time_to_start_from! -t !duration_to_capture!")
ECHO THIS IS JMK1
IF !OverWriteFiles! == Y (SET "OverWrite=-y ") ELSE (SET "OverWrite=-n ")
IF !Convert_Audio1! == Y (
    IF !Convert_TO! == aac ( set "Convert_TO=libfdk_aac" )
    SET "FFmpgConvertStream1=-c:a:0 !Convert_TO! -b:a:0 640k -disposition:a:0 default"
    IF !KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig! == Y (
        SET "FFmpgXtraStream=-c:a copy"
    )
    IF !KeepOrigAudio! == Y (
        SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 copy"
        SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
    )
) ELSE (
    SET "ConvertCodecs=1" 
    SET "KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg=-c:a:0 copy"
    SET "KeepExtraAudio_NoOrig=Y"
)
SET "delm1=^\^>" /c:"^\^<"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=/c:"\^<!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!\^>"^"
SET ^"Exclude-Final=!Exclude-Final:,=%delm1%!^"

dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D-H /B /S |findstr /R %Exclude-Final% /v /i>%TempFilePath%
Echo:   These are the folders being Excluded:           "!Exclude-AlltheseFolders!"
SET "FINALCOMMAND="

SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "ProgramFolder=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg-v2020\bin"
SET "ProbeOptions=-v quiet -select_streams a:0 -show_entries "stream^^=codec_name" -of json"
SET "FilesFound=0" & SET "FilesEncoded=0" & SET "output="
for /F "delims=" %%I in (%TempFilePath%) do (
    SET "output=%drive%%%~pI%%~nxI" & SET folder=%drive%%%~pI & SET "filename=%%~nxI" & SET /A FilesFound+=1
    SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    IF exist "%drive%%%~pIoutput\%%~nxI" (SET "Convert_Audio1=N") ELSE SET "Convert_Audio1=Y"
    IF "!Convert_Audio1!" == "Y" (
        SET "AudioCodec=" & SET "ConvertCodecs="
        for /F "eol={ tokens=1,2 delims=,:[ ]{} " %%B in ('""%ProgramFolder%\ffprobe.exe" %ProbeOptions% "%%I""') do (
            IF "%%~B" == "codec_name" (
                IF not defined AudioCodec (
                    SET "AudioCodec=%%~C"
                )
                IF "%%~C" == "%Codec1%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1"
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec2%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec3%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec4%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec5%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            ) else IF "%%~C" == "%Codec6%" (SET "ConvertCodecs=1" & ECHO Codec is: %%~C
            )
        )
    )
)

IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    ECHO [91m==!TIME!================[0m!Codec1! [94min[0m- %%I [91m=========[0m
)

IF !ConvertCodecs! == 1 (
    IF /I "!output!" == "%%I" (
        SET "output=%~dp0output\!filename!"
        MKDIR "%~dp0output\"
    ) ELSE (
        MKDIR "%drive%%%~pI"
    )
        SET "FINALCOMMAND=ffmpeg !OverWrite!-hide_banner%FFmpgextractTime% -loglevel quiet -hwaccel auto -stats -i "%%I" -map 0:v -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags -map 0:a? -map 0:s:0? -c:s:0 copy -c:v copy %FFmpgXtraStream% %FFmpgConvertStream1% %KeepOrigAudio_ffMpg% "!output!" "
        ECHO this is the command1: !FINALCOMMAND!
        !FINALCOMMAND!
        ECHO [91m=====[0mCOMPLETE[91m===============[0m .
        IF not %FilesEncoded% == 0 ECHO     This one was a failure. Count Encoded so far: "%FilesEncoded%"
        IF not errorlevel 1 SET /A FilesEncoded+=1
        powershell ^(ls '!output!'^).CreationTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).CreationTime
        powershell ^(ls '!output!'^).LastWriteTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).LastWriteTime
        powershell ^(ls '!output!'^).LastAccessTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).LastAccessTime

        for /F "delims=" %%p in ("!ConvertCodecs!") do (
            ECHO THIS IS P: %%p
            ENDLOCAL
            SET /A FilesEncoded=%%p+FilesEncoded
        )

    ) ELSE ( ECHO ##NOT PROCESSING##: !TIME! - %%I ## & ECHO [91m=====--[0mFILE ALREADY EXISTS! [91m======================[0m Next File [91m===========================[0m )
    )
)

IF %FilesFound% == 1 ( SET "PluralS=" ) else SET "PluralS=s"
ECHO [91m***************************************************************************************[0m
ECHO Re-encoded %FilesEncoded% of %FilesFound% video file%PluralS%.
ECHO [91m***************************************************************************************[0m
endlocal
endlocal
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Why use cmd.exe at all? PowerShell is much, much better.

Comment: Can you add the `%%I` loop part of your batch script? You could at least combine all 3 powershell commands into one with semicolons `;`

Comment: I am only familiar with batch and it seems easier.   The '%%I' is way too long to include.   What would the combined powershell comand look like?    Is this is: ` powershell ^(ls '!output!'^).CreationTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).CreationTime | ^(ls '!output!'^).LastWriteTime = ^(ls '%%I'^).LastWriteTime `

Comment: Don't include it, and we cannot help you with it. The choice is yours. However, I will tell you that the task cannot be done using built-in utilities and batch file commands alone, it will need to call on another scripting language and/or a third party utility.

Comment: Ok, Full code added.  My goal overall was to make the batch more efficient and faster.

Comment: I have removed a boat load of lines from your full code, i.e. those which have broken labels and remarks. This was necessary to make your code more readable, and less likely to turn off potential helpers.

Comment: "I am only familiar with batch and it seems easier." In the long run, time spent learning PowerShell will definitely be worth it and will pay off. My recommendation is to make the leap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following copies the specified attributes using a *single*
[`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call:

- Note the use of `gi`, a built-in alias of the [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) cmdlet.

  - `ls` - on Windows - is (unfortunately) a built-in alias of the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet (whose use would work here too, and whose PowerShell-idiomatic alias is `gci`); however, such aliases - named for *other* shells' / platforms' built-in commands / utilities are *best avoided* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591072/45375) for more information.
- Enclosing the entire (implied) `-Command` argument in `"..."` obviates the need for `^`-escaping of individual chars.

```bash
powershell "$target = gi '!orig-file!'; $source = gi '%%i'; 'CreationTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'LastAccessTime' | foreach { $target.$_ = $source.$_ }"
```

Note that the above could still fail in the following cases:

- If a file name happens to contain `'` itself; if so, use `\""...\""` (sic) instead of `'...'`

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for more information.
- If a file name happens to contain `[` and `]`; if so, use `gi -LiteralPath` instead of just `gi`, which implies `gi -Path`.

Comment: Love it, Thank you for teaching the detail!